# Se puede controlar HTTPError demasiadas solicitudes ? goslate

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un `DataFrame` con una longitud de 44k aprox. donde la columna en discordia contiene descripciones en ingles. Entonces se me ocurrió implementar la API de Google translate para python: `goslate`. Pero obviamente, me salta:

> Error 429: Too Many Requests

Es obvio que son muchas peticiones, pero queria saber si hay alguna manera de resolver este problema, seguramente usando `sleep` pero al ser 44k de registros, retrasaría mucho la tarea, supongo.

El código que utilicé fue este:

```
import goslate
df["Descripcion"] = [gs.translate(descripcion, 'es') for descripcion in df['Descripcion']]
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como comentas el servidor de Google simplemente bloquea tu ip al superar el límite de peticiones que tienen establecido. Para superar este límite podrías dividir en fragmentos la columna a traducir y usar alguna de las opciones que especifica la propia [documentación oficial de goslate](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/#query-error):

> - Realizar la peticiones a través de proxies HTTP/SOCK5, ver [Soporte para Proxy](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/#proxy-support)
> - Cambiar el dominio  `gs = Goslate(service_urls=['http://translate.google.de']`)
> - Esperar por 3 segundos antes de realizar una nueva petición.

No obstante, **es muy posible que no estés aprovechando cada petición al máximo**. Google limita la longitud del texto a traducir por petición, pero en cada petición deberías maximizar el texto que envías. Es decir, si tienes tres celdas con texto corto (p.e: `["Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"]`), en vez de enviar una petición por cada celda, puedes unir el texto y enviar una sola.

Podrías hacer esto manualmente o mejor dejar que goslate lo haga por ti. Además podrías usar varios hilos para [hacer concurrente la traducción](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/#concurrent-querying), dado que la mayor parte del tiempo se estará esperando a que llegue la respuesta usar varios hilos debería suponer una buena reducción del tiempo de traducción.

Un ejemplo:

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
import goslate


df = pd.DataFrame({"Descripcion":
     ["Free Google Translate API",
      "A software library for rapid development of hardware-accelerated multitouch applications.",
      "A repository of software for the Python programming language",
      "A pure Python equivalent and a sample application"
      ]})


executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
gs = goslate.Goslate(executor=executor)

df["Descripcion"] = pd.Series(gs.translate(df["Descripcion"], "es"))
```

`max_workers=100` indica el número máximo de de hilos a desplegar y que se encargaran de ir consumiendo texto, generar y enviar la query y recibir la respuesta. No siempre más es mejor, hay siempre un cierto punto de equilibrio, especialmente en Windows donde desplegar nuevos hilos es más costoso (Spawning vs Forking).

A pesar de todo tal como comenta la documentación del propio goslate (referida arriba), Google actualizó su servicio para evitar el uso "abusivo" de Google Translate por parte de bots y crawlers como en el caso de goslate y el resto de paquetes similares. Por lo que es bastante posible que el servidor termine bloqueando. Para aplicaciones y servicios web Google obliga a usar [Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) y "pasar por caja" dado que es un servicio integralmente de pago.

Obviamente, entrando en un uso abusivo del servicio, podemos intentar burlar el bloqueo de varias formas. La más obvia es rotar la ip pública,lo que va  desde comunicarnos con nuestro router forzar un cambio de ip reiniciando la conexión con el ISP (si no es estática) al uso de Tor, servicios proxy, DNS, etc. Por otro lado, podemos intentar crear un crawler propio, con Selenium por ejemplo e intentar en lo posible que no sea detectada nuestra actividad como sospechosa (emulando en lo posible a un usuario humano), lo que no es fácil, Google tiene excelentes recursos para detectar "actividades sospechosas". Aún consiguindolo van a ser siempre métodos relativamente lentos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, cuando pueda probarlo aceptaré la respuesta, por que no me deja hacer esta simple traducción. `aux = gs.translate('hello', 'es')` y me sigue tirando el mismo error. Supongo que debo esperar